# What is the simplest way to hide labels and inputs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the simplest way of hiding labels and inputs in a way that they **do not** affect the layout. See image and the code below. The label *text3* is hidden and there is no extra gap between *text2* and *text4*. In this implementation I put both in `div` container and change its `.style.display` property.

**Edit**: the figure is excactly what I want but the implementation is not good. In other words, how to rewrite the function (e.g. getting rid of div and using css...).

[image: Example of hiding a row]

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="application/javascript">

    function hideableLabelAndTextInput(divId, inputId, labelTxt){
        // container
        var hiderDiv = document.createElement('div');
        hiderDiv.style.display = 'block';
        hiderDiv.id = divId

        // label
        var newLabel = document.createElement('label');
        newLabel.innerHTML = labelTxt;

        // textBox
        var newTextBox = document.createElement('input');
        newTextBox.type = 'text';
        newTextBox.id = 'inputId';

        // grouping
        hiderDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
        hiderDiv.appendChild(newTextBox);

        return hiderDiv;
    }

    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        elem = hideableLabelAndTextInput('div' + i, 'text' + i, 'text' + i);
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }

    document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('div6').style.display = 'none';

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you _want_ to have a gap between 2 and 4? Just trying to make sure I understand

Comment: No, I want it to exactly like that. I just think that my implementation is bad...

Comment: Why not just add the label name as a data attribute to the element it's for? Example `<div data-label="text1">Test 1</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of CSS and JavaScript for this use-case. Essentially what you want to achieve is a simple solution to showing and hiding form elements.

This is what I would suggest for markup:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="/some/processing/script">
    <fieldset id="group-a" class="input-group">
        <label for="my-input-element-1" class="input-wrapper">
            <span>My Element Label</span>
            <input type="text" id="my-input-element-1" value="" />
        </label>

        <!-- Repeat as many times as you need -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#myform label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; /* Set the bottom margin to whatever you want */
}

#myform label > span {
    display: block;    /* display:block will force the input element below it */
    margin: 0 0 3px 0; /* Set the bottom margin to whatever you want */
}

#myform label > input[type="text"] {
    display: block;    /* The default is inline, but we want to span the whole width */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 5px 0; /* Trick to allow an input to span the full width, without poking out of the containing element */
    margin: 0; /* Set the bottom margin to whatever you want */
    text-indent: 5px; /* Indent the text to make it appear normally */
}

#myform label.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

/* OR */

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important; /* Prevent element from affecting the box model, e.g. whitespace between visible, surrounding elements  */
}
```

Now, with this setup in mind, you should only have to add or remove the class `.hidden` from either the containing `<label />` element or apply it to the `<fieldset />` element if you want to hide the whole group.

Also, if you're going to go to the trouble of hiding input fields, I'd recommend setting the disabled attribute, e.g. `<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />` to prevent it's values from being serialized/submitted as part of the form.